# Create customer in GoCardless sandbox returns 403 forbidden

Tags: gocardless

I am attempting to use the GoCardless API sandbox to create a customer but only get a 403 forbidden error

```
  {"error": {
   "message": "Forbidden request",
   "errors": [   {
      "reason": "forbidden",
      "message": "Forbidden request"
   }],
   "documentation_url": "https://developer.gocardless.com/api-reference#forbidden",
   "type": "invalid_api_usage",
   "request_id": "8b870491-e8ca-436c-a602-bb613bba7d96",
   "code": 403
}}
```

I have used OAuth to get a bearer token which I am using for my post to the sandbox url

```
https://api-sandbox.gocardless.com/customers
```

Using this url and the bearer token i can get customers and update a customer that i created manually via the sandbox client portal. If i purposefully make the token an invalid value i get a 401 error instead so I am sure the token is correct.

The documentation for the error type "invalid_api_usage" is as follows

> This is an error with the request you made. It could be an invalid
>   URL, the authentication header could be missing, invalid, or grant
>   insufficient permissions, you may have reached your rate limit, or the
>   syntax of your request could be incorrect. The errors will give more
>   detail of the specific issue.

The fact i can update a customer i believe crosses most of those potential issues of that list.

I am now using the exact post body content of the GoCardless API example for creating customer to verify the syntax should be correct.

```
{
  "customers": {
    "email": "user@example.com",
    "given_name": "Frank",
    "family_name": "Osborne",
    "address_line1": "27 Acer Road",
    "address_line2": "Apt 2",
    "city": "London",
    "postal_code": "E8 3GX",
    "country_code": "GB",
    "metadata": {
      "salesforce_id": "ABCD1234"
    }
  }
}
```

I am running these requests from SoapUI instead of my application so I can be sure I am sending exactly what i am expecting to send.

From the API documentation I understand my application must have approved payment pages to create customers in the live environment however this is prefixed by a statement that this is not restricted in the sandbox environment.

> Restrictions
>
> Whilst the entire GoCardless API is accessible in the sandbox
>   environment, the following restrictions exist in live.
>
> Payment page restrictions
>
> Unless your payment pages have been approved as scheme rules compliant
>   by our sponsor bank you must use the Redirect Flow API to create
>   customers, bank accounts and mandates.
>
> The following endpoints are therefore restricted:
>
> - Customers: Create
> - Customer bank accounts: Create
> - Mandate: Create, Reinstate
> - Javascript flow: All endpoints

It seems to me the 403 forbidden response is exactly what i would be getting if Create Customer was restricted in the sandbox environment however the API documentation explicitly states that this is not the case.

My question is basically what could I be doing wrong? Maybe somebody can spot something I have forgotten or am misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that the sandbox **is** restricted in the same way as the live environment.

The API documentation appears to be worded in a way that suggest the sandbox is unrestricted however this is not the case.

To remove the restriction in the sandbox environment you need to contact GoCardless support and request it.